# Import Error with scikit-surprise

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I ran the example code using scikit-surprise which is a package in python, it showed that "cannot import name similarities".

My operating system is windows 10 and python version is 2.7. When I tried to ran the exactly the same code on the school computer, it succeeded. The operating system in school computer is also windows 10. So it's not the problem of operating system.

I am very confused about what happened. When I commented out the `"from .. import similarities as sims"`, there is another import error `"Import Error: No module named optimize_baselines"`.

When I checked what was `.optimize_baselines and similarities, I found they were all .c files.`
So it seems that it cannot correctly import .c files. But how to deal with that?

Comment: Use [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/). Your setup (which you did not describe) seems to be broken!

Answer (score 0):

You see import error as those packages are not installed in your home computer. So if those are public packages then you can download it via pip or easy_install.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing python3. I installed python2 using anaconda and failed to run the system. I found that the same situation happened on my school computer that the system cannot run with python2 but succeed using python3. I am sorry that I just found I typed "scikit learn" . It should be "scikit surpirse" which is a recommendation system. I guessed the problem was because the C++ compiler. But I am not sure about that.